# How can I make NetworkManager use the global DNS settings from systemd-resolved for all interfaces?

Tags: ubuntu, dns, networkmanager, dhcp, systemd-resolved

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04

I've set some custom DNS servers in `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` (systemd-resolved)

I'm also using NetworkManager.

The servers set in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf are 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1

Now the output of `sudo resolvectl status` looks like:

```
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub
Current DNS Server: 1.0.0.1
       DNS Servers: 1.0.0.1 1.1.1.1

Link 2 (enp8s0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute +LLMNR -mDNS +DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.0.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.0.1 192.168.0.2
```

How can I make the DNS servers for the `enp8s0` interface (which come from DHCP) disappear or show the ones in the global section?

I've tried multiple solutions so far (for example setting ignore-auto-dns like: `nmcli conn modify "WiredETH" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes` and `nmcli conn modify "WiredETH" ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes`), but none change the output of `sudo resolvectl status` for this interface.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Write the dns configuration to `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` as recommended in the [Arch Linux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved#DNS). Then create the symlink.

```
sudo ln -rsf /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
```

Comment: This is strange, now with `nmcli conn modify "WiredETH" ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes` and `nmcli conn modify "WiredETH" ipv6.ignore-auto-dns yes` or the same thing from GUI - turning off automatic DNS for the interface, the DHCP DNS servers no longer appear in the resolvectl output. Maybe it's because now, besides restarting the network services after the change, I'm also disabling and reenabling the interface. If I still get issues with my method will try your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You should write the DNS configuration to `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, not the stub.

Comment: @parsley72 Please read the documentation linked in the answer.

Comment: I don't see where in this doc it is recommended to write the dns conf to this file. Could you point to it? Rather, this file seems to be managed by systemd-resolved. I understand this file is dynamic and points to the internal DNS stub server, that in turn can be configured manually as described here : https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/systemd-resolved#Manually. In my understanding you should not edit this file at all.

Comment: @GAD3R how to achieve the same for some other configuration like mdns ?  resolved.conf only modifies global settings not per interface settings. systemd-resolve --set-mdns  works but it doesn't persists accross boot ?

Comment: `/etc/resolve.conf` symlinked says "# This is `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` managed by `man:systemd-resolved(8)`. # Do not edit." In my understanding if you use `systemd-resolved` then edit `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`. The link to the ArchWiki is about `systemd-resolved` - it says "The resolver can be configured by editing `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`". Check the results with `resolvectl status`.